# error while installing pencil project on 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, deb, error-handling, pencil

I try to install pencil project form the [official .deb](http://evoluspencil.googlecode.com/files/evoluspencil_2.0.5_all.deb) file. and i received...

```
 sudo dpkg -i evoluspencil_2.0.5_all.deb 
(Reading database ... 364296 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack evoluspencil_2.0.5_all.deb ...
Unpacking evoluspencil (2.0.5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive evoluspencil_2.0.5_all.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/pencil', which is also in package pencil 0.4.4b-0ubuntu5
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 evoluspencil_2.0.5_all.deb
```

i tried both software center installation and terminal installation both gave the same error.

what would be the problem..?

Answer (score 0):

The problem would be the clash between the existing pencil program and the one you are trying to install.

If you don't need the existing app, just delete it :

```
sudo apt-get purge pencil
```

After that

```
sudo dpkg -i evoluspencil_2.0.5_all.deb
```

just should work.

I had the same problem, but a friend actually *read* the error-message and helped me out... Thanks Tijs!